# Bernoulli trial confidence intervals

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, proportion, bernoulli-distribution

I am working through an example in my notes and I am not sure how they arrived at the solution.
The question reads:

"7 successes are observed in 20 trials. Find a 95% confidence interval for p"

The resulting confidence interval they give is (0.15,0.59).
When I use binom.test in R it gives this exact answer, however I'm not sure what formula they have used to obtain the solution by hand.

Answer (score 1):

7 successes were observed.

Think about how likely it is to see 7 successes out of 20 with different values of p.
If it is very unlikely, then that p should not be in the 95% confidence interval.

If p=0.1539, then there is only a 2.5% chance of getting 7 or more successs. So, on one side, any p less than 0.1539 would have less than 2.5% chance of getting 7 or more successes. Those values of p should not be included in the CI.

Likewise, if p=0.592, then there is only a 2.5% of seeing 7 or fewer successes. Therefore, on the other side, any p>0.592 should not be in the CI.

You are actually making two one-sided 97.5% confidence regions and then the intersection of both of them is the two-sided 95% CI.

```
> binom.test(7,20)

    Exact binomial test

data:  7 and 20
number of successes = 7, number of trials = 20, p-value = 0.2632
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1539092 0.5921885
sample estimates:
probability of success 
                  0.35 

> 1-pbinom(6,20,0.1539)
[1] 0.02499244
> pbinom(7,20,0.592)
[1] 0.02510285
```